# How I pick all elements of a table cell by index using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need all the elements of the cells using jQuery.

Let us assume I have three columns and if I give second column index then response should be only from second column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @hasseem , what is column here , is it a div ?? or table row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#table1").find("tr td:nth-child(3)")
```

This will give you all the `td` elements from the 3rd column (change the '3' for your value)

Cheers

Comment: +1 for nth-child, but this won't give the contents, only the `td`

Comment: Thanks :). But but he doesn't specify he needs the contents, just says 'cells' and 'elements cells' :S, I assumed he wants the `td`s.

Comment: `all the elements of the cells` is the wording that made me think he needs what's inside.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each row and push the `.text()` from the td at the index you are looking for into an array.

See http://jsfiddle.net/derekddecker/YWX9F/